# Bash alias to open Vim at last cursor position mark

Tags: unix, vim, bash

The mark `"` in Vim takes you to your last cursor position. I want to create an alias that will open my Vim instance and jump to that mark; something which is obviously extremely useful.

This works from the command line:

```
$ vim -c "'\"" File.cpp
```

Now I want to make an alias for this:

```
$ alias v='vim -c "'\""'
```

Well that's not going to work! You need to escape the first single quote you say...

```
$ alias v='vim -c "\'\""'
```

Hmm. That didn't work either... So I try a whole lot of variations of single quoted and double quoted madness, bang my head against the table and load up stackoverflow in my browser, and here we are.

How do I properly escape this alias?

**Edit**

In fact there is a better way to do this `:h last-position-jump`.

This autocommand jumps to the last known position in a file just after opening it, if the `'"` mark is set:

`:au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g'\"" | endif`

Comment: Doesn't this happen automatically? Whenever I open a file, the starting position is always at the position of my last edit.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe there's some magical setting in your vimrc that I am ignorant of.

Comment: Indeed. See `:h last-position-jump`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks completely obscure, but should work:

```
alias v='vim -c "'"'"'\""'
```

That's a single-quoted `vim -c "`, followed by a double-quoted `'`, followed by a single-quoted `\""`...

Comment: So you are basically concatenating 'vim -c "' and "'" and '\""' right? Can you also do it with escaping?

Comment: @Tomas: Yes, it is doing concatenation. With only using double-quoted arguments the escaped version would look like this: `alias v="vim -c \"'\\\"\""`

Answer (score 3):

Your question is an example of a situation in which functions are superior to aliases:

```
v() { vim -c "'\"" "$@"; }
```

Comment: You should wrap the `$@` in double-quotes (ie `"$@"`) in case there are spaces in any of the filenames.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/). It let's you save one or more shell instances (where one or more could be running vim) and saves their exact contents as if your computer would be idling. In particular, it's perfect for having many tabs and files open on a remote computer.

So instead of just going to the last mark, you'd simply type `screen -r mysession` and you'd restore not just the last position of the cursor, but all your buffers/tabs/shell instances/other programs and what not.

But perhaps you knew that already.